# Modal box after conditional statement in php

Tags: javascript, php, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I've found in this [link](http://netdna.webdesignerdepot.com/uploads7/creating-a-modal-window-with-html5-and-css3/demo.html) a modal box written in CSS and HTML5 and I would like to display this after instruction statement written in php, for example:

```
<?php
$a = 1;
$b = 1;

if($a==$b)
{
echo 'a=b';
} else {
DISPLAY MODAL BOX;
?>
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
you can use following:-



     <?php
        $a = 1;
        $b = 1;

        if($a==$b)
        {
        echo 'a=b';
        } else { ?>
    <!-- here you can write your modal html.... -->
<style>
    .modalDialog {
        position: fixed;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
        z-index: 99999;
        opacity:0;
        -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
        -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
        transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
        pointer-events: none;
    }

    .modalDialog:target {
        opacity:1;
        pointer-events: auto;
    }

    .modalDialog > div {
        width: 400px;
        position: relative;
        margin: 10% auto;
        padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        background: #fff;
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
        background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
    }

    .close {
        background: #606061;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        line-height: 25px;
        position: absolute;
        right: -12px;
        text-align: center;
        top: -10px;
        width: 24px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-weight: bold;
        -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
        -moz-border-radius: 12px;
        border-radius: 12px;
        -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
        box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    }

    .close:hover { background: #00d9ff; }
    </style>


    <a href="#openModal">Open Modal</a>

    <div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
        <div>
            <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
            <h2>Modal Box</h2>
            <p>This is a sample modal box that can be created using the powers of CSS3.</p>
            <p>You could do a lot of things here like have a pop-up ad that shows when your website loads, or create a login/register form for users.</p>
        </div>
    </div>

      <?php }  ?>
```

Comment: How it works? #openModal responsible for display box.

Comment: When you click on "Open Modal" Link, it will redirect to "#openModal", which is on same page, so it will display 'id="openModal"' div content.